# Can you load test (perf-test) an angular application

Tags: angular, performance-testing

an i run a performance test on an angular application with 5000+ users in parallel sessions to test if my application client runs effectively ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular? It's a single person who operates the browser, not 5000. If you're testing the backend, then test only it. Emulating user actions in several thousands browsers provides enormous overhead that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Load testing tools act on **HTTP protocol level** so they don't care regarding underlying technology, just make sure you properly configure your load testing tool to represent real user using real browser including (but not limited to)

- Authentication
- [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))
- [HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [HTTP Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
- [AJAX requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))
- etc.

If you're uncertain regarding which tool to choose there is a number of [free and open source load testing solutions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) you could consider to conduct the load testing.

Comment: The problem is when i test the http endpoint for my application, my underline javascript logic (ngOnInit) does not run